# Wrong font displayed with DrawString, was fine on dev machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, system.drawing

I have a class in an ASP.net project, with a function returns a Bitmap object. Everything worked fine on my dev machine, but when I set the site up on a new server, all my text (written to the image with DrawString) appears in the wrong font. I copied the TrueType font file from my machine to the server, installed the font, restarted IIS, rebooted, but it still shows the wrong font.

Server is Win Server 2008 w/ IIS7. Dev machine is Win7 pro, Visual Studio 2010 Pro SP1.

Simplified version of my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class MyImageClass
Public Function GetMyImage() As Bitmap
    Dim oBitmap as Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.MyImage)
    Dim oGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap)
    oGraphic.TextRenderingHint = Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

    Dim oBrushText As New SolidBrush(Color.White)

    Dim ffamily As New FontFamily("Freestyle Script")

    Dim oFont1 As New Font(ffamily, 15, FontStyle.Regular)

    oGraphic.DrawString("My Text", oFont1, oBrushText, 10, 10)

    Return oBitmap
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Can you create screen shots of what it should look like and what it does look like. You'll have to post them as links, but it might help someone work out what's going on.

Comment: Can't right now, but font in my image that should be Freestyle Script is instead a sans serif font, maybe Arial.

Comment: Can you select the font on the server in Word?

Comment: In WordPad, yes. And I created a test page that would return all the fonts available on the server, and it returned FreeStyle Script, too.

Comment: And now when I come back after holiday break, my problem code is working as expected. I don't know what happened between Friday and now that made it start working (neither restarting the site in IIS or restarting the server worked Friday), but it is working... 

If anyone has an idea, it could help when I do installs of this same code on other servers in the coming days.